# proving piece wise function is discontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Visually, we can check to see that the following function is discontinuous 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
 3x^2+\cos(2\pi x) & x\lt 3\\
 x-3 & x\geq 3
\end{cases}
$$

But how do we prove it?

Comment: By the definition? check the limits..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $\lim_{x\to3^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to3^+} (x - 3) = 3 - 3 = 0$
- $\lim_{x\to3^-} f(x) = \lim_{x\to3^-} (3x^2+\cos(2\pi x)) = 3(3^2)+\cos(6\pi) = 27+1 = 28 \ne 0$

Hence $\lim_{x\to3^+} f(x) = f(3) \ne \lim_{x\to3^-} f(x)$.  $f$ is discontinuous at $x=3$.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$\lim_{x\to 3^-}(3x^2+\cos(2\pi x))=27+\cos(6\pi)=...?$$

Comment: It should be $3x^2$ instead of $9x^2$.